# Nonexistence of Morphisms between Schemes of Differing Characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, positive-characteristic

So I'm new to this whole scheme theory business. I'm working my way through Gortz and I produced a solution to an exercise but it seemed too easy. I'm hoping someone can either tell me that I am indeed doing things correctly, or show me in what way my proof is insufficient.
This isn't homework but just my own personal reading. I know it's probably elementary, but please bare with me.

**The Statement** Let k and k' be fields of differing characteristic. Let X and X' be schemes over k and k' respectively, X $\ne \emptyset$. Then, there are no morphisms X $\rightarrow$ X'.

**My Suggestion** Suppose $f$:X$\rightarrow$X'. Let p and q be the characteristic of k and k' respectively. Then, $f^\#_x : O_{Y,f(x)} \rightarrow O_{X,x}$ is a local homomorphism of rings. Since $f^\#_x$ is local it extends to a map $O_{Y,f(x)}/M'$ to $k(O_{X,x})/M$ of the relevant fields given by taking the quotient by the relevant maximal ideals. We claim $O_{Y,f(x)}/M'$ and $O_{X,x}/M$ have characteristic p and q respectively, because they are the quotient of direct limits of rings of characteristic p and q.*  But the category of fields is not connected, and has connected component the fields of various characteristic. Hence, there can be no such morphism.

- * So this is the assertion I am least sure of. Is characteristic preserved in the inductive limit? If so, what would be a good reference for me to see the proof of this, or is it obvious and I'm just not seeing it?

Lastly, I want to know if this is a general sort of argument in scheme theory. Should I try this approach more often when disproving the existence of morphisms, or is passing to the quotient of the stalk not the right idea?

Comment: Isn't it enough to know that there is some homomorphism $k \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/M$? Thinking about characteristic for things that aren't fields makes my head hurt. Also, taking stalks is always worth a shot.

Comment: Man. Yes. It is isn't it. $\mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow k \rightarrow O_{X,x}/M$ so it must be characteristic p. Well, thank you Hoot. Can you make that an answer so I can go ahead and accept it? By the way, how do you do that nice O? I've been wondering.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have something to say about colimits and maybe your last, more philosophical, question. If no one does this I can promote it to an answer later. Regarding TeX: `\mathcal{O}` or `\mathscr{O}` depending on your taste.

Comment: Excellent thank you. Yes it would be nice to have something like that. I was sort of hoping someone would post something like that.

Comment: I should also note that you can right-click on any TeX on the site and view the source. And yes, let's hope that person comes along. As a silly example, you could say that a dominant map of irreducible varieties can't raise the dimension, because of what happens to the fields at the generic points.

Comment: Good pro-tip on the right click, thank you, I had no idea.

Comment: "So I'm new to this whole scheme theory business" Welcome to  Schemeland: its mysteries, its dangers, its revelations, its beauty...

Comment: Your argument is fine, by the way. To check that the characteristic is preserved by direct limits and quotients, you can just check that the property of containing a copy of $\mathbb Q$, or containing a copy of $\mathbb F_p$, is so preserved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Applying the global section functor $\Gamma$ to the given morphisms we obtain ring morphisms $k'\to \Gamma (X', \mathcal O_{X'}) \to \Gamma (X, \mathcal O_{X})$ and $k\to \Gamma (X, \mathcal O_{X})$.
The second morphism and the composition of the first two ones show that we have ring morphisms $k'\to \Gamma (X, \mathcal O_{X})$ and $k\to \Gamma (X, \mathcal O_{X})$.
In other words the ring  $\Gamma (X, \mathcal O_{X})$ is both a $k$-algebra and a $k'$-algebra.
 But a non-zero ring $A$ like here $\Gamma (X, \mathcal O_{X})$ cannot simultaneously be an algebra over two fields $k,k'$ of different characteristics because the characteristic of a non-zero algebra over a field is the same as that of  the field.
This contradiction shows that no scheme-morphism $X\to X'$ exists.

Comment: what is the global section functor?